# GetPhysicallyInstalledMemory function - undefined reference in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to get the Physically Installed RAM of the computer among other system information.
Once I try to compile the code, it gives the error "undefined reference to `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` along with a warning that states that's an implicit declaration.

I'm using Code::Blocks 17.12 and the latest GCC.

```
#define WINVER 0x0A00
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{

    long ram;
    BOOL Checkram;

    Checkram = GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(&ram);
    printf("Installed RAM is: %lu", ram);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm very new to C programming and I did read the Microsoft documentation but it still didn't help me to solve this problem.

Update:
I've compiled it with Visual Studio and now it works.

Comment: GCC means you are probably using a 3rd-party windows.h so you need to make sure that function is actually declared in one of the headers. It also needs a pointer to a 64-bit value, not a long.

Comment: I can only find the function "GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()", do you mean that? See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getphysicallyinstalledsystemmemory

Comment: It might not exist in the files you are using, use the official SDK from Microsoft and/or Visual Studio instead of GCC.

Comment: Aha, got it, didn't know there was a difference between them.

Comment: @just_C So your problem is solved now? If the only problem was, that the function name was wrong, you should consider to delete this question

Comment: @Ctx Yes you are probably right

Comment: I fixed the error type above, the problem was in the compiler.

Comment: This example works for me with the latest gcc (once I fixed the `ram` variable type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've switched to visual studio and it resolved the problem.